# Adding items from a database to a combo box and a text box

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            listParent.Add("Chocolate");
            listParent.Add("Biscuit");
            listParent.Add("Milk");
            listParent.Add("Sugar");
            listParent.Add("Flour");
            listParent.Add("Ice Cream");

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Kandos"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Edna"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Mars"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Rovello"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Maliban"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Munchee"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Maam"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Anchor"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Nespray"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Raththi"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Lakspray"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sugar", "Arpico"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sugar", "Cargils"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Flour", "Prima"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Flour", "MDK"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Elephant House"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Keels"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Highland"));



            foreach (var item in listParent)
            {
                cmbParent.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        List<String> listParent = new List<String>();
        List<Tuple<String, String>> listChild = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
```

In my c# program I have two combo boxes. One combo box changes its value according to the first combo box. The first combo box shows "*product category*" & the second one shows "*product brand*" according to the first one. I have already written the code that does this correctly.

Now I have entered all the "*product brands*" with their "*prices*" in to a database.  I want to add a text box that shows the price of the currently selected product from the second combo box.  In other words, when the value of the second combo box changes the *price* textbox should also change.

If I have entered the price of chocolate in database as $100 when I choose chocolate from combo box, the text box value should be 100.

Help me to write the code. I am new to c#.

Comment: You should consider posting your existing code -- it will make it far easier for people to give answers to your question.

Comment: Ok I will post my code.

Comment: I have posted my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add event handler to your comboboxes.

Add `SelectedItemChanged` event hander to your `cmbParent` combobox, so when user changes product category, you can filter `listChild` and remove other product categories. Then, add those filtered items to your other combo (`cmbChild`).

Next thing is to add `SelectedItemChanged` event hander to your `cmbChild` combobox. When user selects something from that combo, event will fire and you can connect to database and fetch prices.

Take a look at code that implements said things.

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            listParent.Add("Chocolate");
            listParent.Add("Biscuit");
            listParent.Add("Milk");
            listParent.Add("Sugar");
            listParent.Add("Flour");
            listParent.Add("Ice Cream");

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Kandos"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Edna"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Mars"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Chocolate", "Rovello"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Maliban"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Munchee"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Biscuit", "Maam"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Anchor"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Nespray"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Raththi"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Milk", "Lakspray"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sugar", "Arpico"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sugar", "Cargils"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Flour", "Prima"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Flour", "MDK"));

            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Elephant House"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Keels"));
            listChild.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Ice Cream", "Highland"));



            foreach (var item in listParent)
            {
                cmbParent.Items.Add(item);
            }

            cmbParent.SelectedIndexChanged += CmbParent_SelectedIndexChanged;
            cmbChild.SelectedIndexChanged += CmbChild_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        List<String> listParent = new List<String>();
        List<Tuple<String, String>> listChild = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();


        private void CmbChild_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string selectedBrand = (string)cmbChild.SelectedItem;

            //get data from database
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("[your connection string]");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            command.Connection = conn;

            command.CommandText = "Select Price from [your table] where productBrand = @productBrand";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productBrand", selectedBrand);

            conn.Open();
            decimal price = (decimal)command.ExecuteScalar();

            txtPrice.Text = price.ToString();

            conn.Close();
        }

        private void CmbParent_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Tuple<String, String>> productsList = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
            productsList = listChild.Where(x => x.Item1 == (string)cmbParent.SelectedItem).ToList();

            cmbChild.Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in productsList)
            {
                cmbChild.Items.Add(item.Item2);
            };
        }
```

Comment: When I get data from my table. This shows  many errors. I can't understand it. Please tell me a bit about that part of the code

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. You are asking how to get data from database?

Comment: Yeah. The code of it. I typed "SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(I added connection string here). Then can you tell me the next part of this

Comment: I've edited an answer and added fetching price from database. Due to a very little info about your database, maybe this code won't work, but you should easily understand what I'm trying to achieve. Good luck

Comment: if you do, please post your code. It's a much easier to help you if you tried something and wrote some code. If not then it's mostly guessing

Comment: This code is not working. When I run the program it runs upto this point & there is a error message like "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Dll." and so on. I typed only your code. What can I do for this now?

Comment: The `SQLExecption` should have more detail about the specific problem -- perhaps within an `InnerExecption`.  Use your debugger to drill down into more detail about the `SQLException` and any InnerException`s on the execption chain.

Comment: Can you give me an example for that. i am new to c#